# Ember Data with Local Storage Example

Tags: javascript, ember.js, local-storage

Im trying to piece together a simple working Ember data example using the local storage adapter (https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter). I purposely want to keep this simple and in a single file so I can start to understand whats going on.

Does anybody have an example they can share that includes local-storage CRUD operations (console output is all I need) ?

Regards,

Carl

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/kiwiupover/ember-weather/blob/master/app/routes/locations.js this is a weather dashboard that saves and deletes locations to localstorage.

http://emberweather.com/locations/seattle-washington

I hope that helps.